# How to fix Codeigniter cart stock control issue?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I add products to the cart, but when I want to check the stock, I encounter problems. When I first add the product, the `$this->cart->contents()` basket is empty at the first stage, so the product amount appears to be 0. When I add the product to the basket again, the old amount of the product I added appears. I cannot control the stock. Can you give me an idea of how you can do this?

So this is what I want to do; To control the amount of product in the basket and the amount of product in me and to prevent the process of adding to the basket My only problem now is that he sees the old amount in the basket. Is there anyone to help?

I show the problem with gif: [giphy](https://media.giphy.com/media/FeocS1y8W8toUq866M/source.gif)

```php
public function add()
    {
        $response       = array();
        $opt_arr        = array();
        $urun_id        = $this->input->post('product_id');
        $miktar         = $this->input->post('quantity');
        $select_opt     = $this->input->post('select_opt');
        $radio_opt      = $this->input->post('radio_opt');
        
        $where = $this->yurun_model->urun(array("urun_id" => $urun_id));
        $ayarlar = ayarlar();

        if (!$where) {
            $response['durum'] = 'error';
            $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Bulunamadı!';
            print_r(json_encode($response));
            die;
        }

        $sepet_Say  = [];
        $radio_Say  = [];
        $select_Say = [];
        if ($this->cart->contents()) {
            foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items){
                if ($items['id']==$urun_id) {
                    if ($items['options']['radio_opt']==$radio_opt) {
                        $radio_Say[] = $items['qty'];
                    }
                    if ($items['options']['select_opt']==$select_opt) {
                        $select_Say[] = $items['qty'];
                    }
                    if ($where->urun_radio==0 || $where->urun_select==0) {
                        $urun_gu = $where->urun_stok;

                        if ($urun_gu==0) {
                            $response['durum'] = 'error';
                            $response['s_baslik'] = 'Bu Ürün Stoklarımızda Kalmamıştır!';
                            print_r(json_encode($response));
                            die;
                        }

                        // if ($urun_gu<=$items['qty']) {
                        //  $response['durum'] = 'error';
                        //  $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Stok Sınırını Geçtiniz! Ürün Stok Sayısı : '.$urun_gu.' Adettir';
                        //  print_r(json_encode($response));
                        //  die;
                        // }
                    }
                    $sepet_Say[] = $items['qty'];
                }
            }
            $qty_sonuc      = array_sum($sepet_Say);
            $radio_sonuc    = array_sum($radio_Say);
            $select_sonuc   = array_sum($select_Say);
        }else{
            $qty_sonuc      = 0;
            $radio_sonuc    = 0;
            $select_sonuc   = 0;
        }

        if ($where->urun_ifiyat!='0.00') {
            $fiyat = $where->urun_ifiyat;
        }else{
            $fiyat = $where->urun_fiyat;
        }

        if ($where->urun_radio>0 || $where->urun_select>0) {
            $stok = 0;
        }else{
            $stok = $where->urun_stok;
        }

        if ($where->urun_radio!=0) {
            if ($where->urun_radio!=0) {
                if (!$radio_opt) {
                    $response['durum'] = 'error';
                    $response['s_baslik'] = 'Lütfen Ürün Özelliği Seçin!';
                    print_r(json_encode($response));
                    die;
                }
            }

            $urun_radio_json  = json_decode($where->urun_radio_json);
            $radio_say  = [];
            foreach ($urun_radio_json as $radio) {
                if ($radio_opt==$radio->id) {
                    if ($radio->stok<$miktar) {
                        $response['durum'] = 'error';
                        $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Stok Sınırını Geçtiniz! Ürün Stok Sayısı : '.$radio->stok.' Adettir';
                        print_r(json_encode($response));
                        die;
                    }
                    if ($radio->stok<=$radio_sonuc) {
                        $response['durum'] = 'error';
                        $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Stok Sınırını Geçtiniz! Ürün Stok Sayısı : '.$radio->stok.' Adettir';
                        print_r(json_encode($response));
                        die;
                    }
                    $radio_say[] = $radio->stok;
                }
            }
            $radio_sayi = array_sum($radio_say);
        }else{
            $radio_sayi = 0;
        }



        if ($where->urun_select!=0) {
            if (!$select_opt) {
                $response['durum'] = 'error';
                $response['s_baslik'] = 'Lütfen Ürün Özelliği Seçin!';
                print_r(json_encode($response));
                die;
            }

            if ($select_opt==0) {
                $response['durum'] = 'error';
                $response['s_baslik'] = 'Lütfen Ürün Özelliği Seçin!';
                print_r(json_encode($response));
                die;
            }
            $urun_select_json = json_decode($where->urun_select_json);
            $select_say = [];
            foreach ($urun_select_json as $select) {
                if ($select_opt==$select->id) {
                    if ($select->stok<$miktar) {
                        $response['durum'] = 'error';
                        $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Stok Sınırını Geçtiniz! Ürün Stok Sayısı : '.$select->stok.' Adettir';
                        print_r(json_encode($response));
                        die;
                    }
                    if ($select->stok<=$select_sonuc) {
                        $response['durum'] = 'error';
                        $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Stok Sınırını Geçtiniz! Ürün Stok Sayısı : '.$select->stok.' Adettir';
                        print_r(json_encode($response));
                        die;
                    }
                    $select_say[] = $select->stok;
                }
            }
            $select_sayi = array_sum($select_say);
            if ($select_sayi!=0) {
            }
            
        }else{
            $select_sayi = 0;
        }

        $varyant_stok = $radio_sayi+$select_sayi;

        if ($varyant_stok==0) {
            $urun_stok = $stok;
        }else{
            $urun_stok = $varyant_stok;
        }

        if ($urun_stok==0) {
            $response['durum'] = 'error';
            $response['s_baslik'] = 'Bu Ürün Stoklarımızda Kalmamıştır!';
            print_r(json_encode($response));
            die;
        }

        if ($urun_stok<$miktar) {
            $response['durum'] = 'error';
            $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Stok Sınırını Geçtiniz! Ürün Stok Sayısı : '.$urun_stok.' Adettir';
            print_r(json_encode($response));
            die;
        }

        if ($where->urun_kdv) {
            $kdv = $fiyat*$where->urun_kdv/100;
            $fiyat_sonuc = $fiyat+$kdv;
        }elseif ($ayarlar->urun_kdv) {
            $kdv = $fiyat*$ayarlar->urun_kdv/100;
            $fiyat_sonuc = $fiyat+$kdv;
        }else{
            $fiyat_sonuc = $fiyat;
        }
        

        $data = array(
            "id"            => $where->urun_id,
            "name"          => $where->urun_ad,
            "qty"           => $miktar,
            "price"         => number_format((float)$fiyat_sonuc, 2, '.', ''),
            "options"       => array('select_opt' => $select_opt, 'radio_opt' => $radio_opt),
            "kupon"         => "",
            "indirim"       => 0,
            "eski_fiyat"    => "",
            "kdvsiz_fiyat"  => $fiyat,
            "kdv"           => $where->urun_kdv,
            "kargo"         => 0

        );

        $this->cart->insert($data);

        $response['durum'] = 'success';
        $response['s_baslik'] = 'Ürün Sepete Eklendi!';
        print_r(json_encode($response));
    }
```

Comment: from the current docs: 
[the Codeigniter Cart Library is **DEPRECATED and should not be used**. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#shopping-cart-class)

Comment: @Vickel there is nothing to do with that. a completely logical operation is required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way.

```php
if ($select->stok<=$select_sonuc+$miktar) {
```